# Why do macros take more space than an equivalently defined function?

Tags: function, memory, macros, c-preprocessor

From [Programming in C (3rd edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672326663), page 309:

> Because macros are directly substituted into the program by the
>   preprocessor, they inevitably use more memory space than an
>   equivalently defined function.

In which sense do macros take more space than an equivalently defined function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your quote says, the macro's text is substituted straight into the code by the preprocessor. e.g.

```
#define ABSOLUTE_VALUE( x ) ( ((x) < 0) ? -(x) : (x) )

int absoluteSum(int a, int b) {
    return ABSOLUTE_VALUE(a) + ABSOLUTE_VALUE(b);
}
```

Becomes:

```
int absoluteSum(int a, int b) {
    return ( ((a) < 0) ? -(a) : (a) ) + ( ((b) < 0) ? -(b) : (b) );
}
```

after preprocessing. A traditional function call does not do this. If you use a macro twice in the code, the macro's code is substituted twice, increasing the memory footprint. With a traditional function, the macro's code is only found and compiled once, as below.

```
int abs(int value) {
    return ( ((value) < 0) ? -(value) : (value) );
}

int absoluteSum(int a, int b) {
    return abs(a) + abs(b);
}
```